# Angularjs data-ng-include not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am using angular js to create single page application. where i am calling a function which return url for data-ng-include.

Example:

```
<script>
  function theURL(){
  return 'demo.html';
  }
</script>


 <div ng-app="">
  <div data-ng-include="'theURL()'">
  </div>
 </div>
```

but the above code is not taking the url returned from the function hence the partial page is not load. can you please help?

Comment: <body>
     <div ng-app="">
      <div data-ng-include="'theURL()'">
      </div>
     </div>
   </body>
 I did called it in body like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div ng-include="theURL()"></div>
```

But if it does not work, where is your Controller? Where is your $scope?

```
$scope.theUrl = function(){
  return 'demo.html';
}
```

This inside your controller will work 100%.